# Buildbot figure out if there were any changes

Tags: buildbot

I have a Buildbot scheduler to run builds every night. Is there a way to configure Buildbot so that it does the builds only if there were changes since the last build?

-Ilya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the `Nightly` scheduler's `onlyIfChanged` option - http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/cfg-schedulers.html#nightly-scheduler.

Comment: `onlyIfChanged` option will work. There is also `branch` option to specify the branch. But I'm curious, how does the scheduler know which repository it applies to?

Comment: The `branch` parameter is a holdover from the days when Buildbot supported only a single codebase.  With multiple codebases (in multiple repositories), it's not a very useful parameter.

Comment: Is it still needed? The `checkconfig` says that this parameter is required. What should it be set to in case of several repositories?

Comment: Hm, I think that's a bug.  It looks like this was fixed in [March 2012](https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/commit/83e27f5c#diff-f44457fbb17a7eb67ceb7808f125aaaeL249) but then reverted in [May 2012](https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/commit/cb42c19a#diff-f44457fbb17a7eb67ceb7808f125aaaeL246).  But looking at the rest of the code I think there are deeper assumptions about branch.